# SelfValidation in DataAnnotations?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, enterprise-library, data-annotations

With Validation Application block, there's the following functionality:

1. Creating Custom attributes
2. Creating SelfValidation on the type
3. Ability to read from external config file

I plan to use the DataAnnotations to replace the Validation application block. Are the above possible with DataAnnotations? If so, how'd I implement them?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: VAB 5.0 (just released) allows validating DataAnnotations attributes. This might be interesting for you. This allows you to use VAB as validation framework, but use .NET common declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes they are possible.

Creating a very simple custom attribute;

```
public class IsApplicantOldEnoughAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null) return false;
        DateTime enteredDate;

        try
        {
            enteredDate = (DateTime)value;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
        if ((DateTime.Today.Year - enteredDate.Year) >= 14)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Reading from a config file is the same as any code that reads from a config file.

Unsure what you mean by self validation though.  Could you please fill me in and I'll try to give an example.

Comment: @griegs Check out the DateTime.TryParse() method. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx

Comment: @griegs - SelfValidation is a way to apply validation at the type level. Also, is it possible to do rulesets with DataAnnotations?

Answer (score 0):

you can simple add the IValidatableObject Interface to your Type:

```
public class MyClass : IValidatableObject {
 public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
 {
   return ...
 }
}
```

this works with ValidationContext etc.